# Spring jdbc transaction not commit

Tags: spring, transactions, jdbctemplate, autocommit

I have following Spring configuration:

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"       
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd        
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd" >
```

Beans with database and transaction management are configured as below:

```
<bean id="sufe.ncm.docDao" class="DocDaoImpl" scope="singleton">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="sufe.ncm.jdbcTemplate"/>        
</bean>

<bean id="sufe.ncm.jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="sufe.ncm.filterDB"/>
    <property name="fetchSize" value="5000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sufe.ncm.filterDB" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="..."/>
    <property name="username" value="..."/>
    <property name="password" value="..."/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="minIdle" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="5"/>
</bean>

<context:annotation-config/>
<tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="sufe.ncm.filterDB"></property>
</bean>
```

`DocDaoImpl` class implements method `updateData` from interface `DocDao`:

```
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = SQLException.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public synchronized void updateData() {
        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(UPDATE_QUERY_1);
        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(UPDATE_QUERY_1);
    }
```

Because `dataSource` has set autocommit option on false, I expect that transaction will be committed only when both batchUpdates operation will finish whithout error. Unfortunatelly, unless both updates finishes whithout error, commit is not performed and I don't see any changes in database. Whats wrong ? Why `@Transactional`  annotation doesn't work and commit is not performed ?

Comment: Try putting the name of TransactionManager inside of @Transactional

Comment: Where is called updateData() ? `In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional.`

Comment: Ivan Rodrigues: it helps. Thanks.

Comment: No, it still doesn't work. Transactions aren't commited....

Comment: Is this inference based after executing Junits ? if yes, the methods need to be annotated with @Rollback(false) to see the actual results in database.